# ASP.NET Report Viewer runs but doesn't show any data

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have many pages containing the report viewer control, all of them work fine expect 4 reports. When I browse to any one of these reports, the page executes, but nothing is shown.

Those reports take 1 min to 3 min to finish the execution.

I can't find any exception or error in the logs.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: hi, can you see some header or only display a blank page?

Comment: Set the display to Async and see if you can locate a "Loading bar..."

Comment: No i can't see the headers, only a blank page

Comment: You mean AsyncRendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to set     AsyncPostBackTimeout property to the script manager of the aspx page.

The default is 90 second.